# Low tesseract accuracy when detecting numbers

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I am working on OCR project in Python and using layoutparser library which implements tesseract to do the detection. I have issues trying to detect one number in the document as i cannot get the accuracy over 45% (depending on preprocessing methods it's between 30 and 45%) everything else is between 80 and 100%. I have tried multiple different methods of preprocessing but without any success so I want to know if there is anything else to try.

Original image is a scan of document, with multiple fields and a graph (i cannot share original image as it contains client data). One of the fields contains the number im interested in. First i tried doing OCR on whole document, which gave me the best results (45% accuracy). Image was converted to grayscale, resized to height 1800, while keeping aspect ratio and then I applied canny edge detector from opencv. The only tesseract parameter used was `languages="slk"` as i need it to detect other data as well. I wasn't really happpy with the results so i thought why not try to cut out just the number and do detection on that.

So i cut out the field (from grayscaled and resized image) which contains the number + some area around it since i dont know where exactly the number is, i can only guess. This is how the cutout looks like [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JD45.jpg). It always contains only digits and is not skewed. Best result i achieved was 33% accuracy with the following preprocessing:

```
image = adjust_gamma(image, 1.2)
image = denoise_tv_chambolle(image, multichannel=True)
image = cv2.normalize(src=image, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
image = cv2.bitwise_not(image)
```

Tesseract parameters used: `languages="slk", config="--psm 6, digits"`. Bitwise_not is used so the resulting image is black digits on white background, which should result in tesseract giving better results.

Other things i tried for preprocessing were thresholding(binary and otsu), adaptive thresholding, blur, gaussian blur, dilation, erosion, all different --psm parameters and LSTM model for tesseract. None of them gave better results. I read through tesseract preprocessing documentation and multiple other stackoverflow questions with similar problems. I am thankful for any ideas about what to do to get better results.

Comment: In that case better you can change your ocr techniques. you can use easyocr or google vision for this case. It will give better output. Is there any compulsion to go with layoutparser?

Comment: The executed code for easyocr based on your cropped image is ,

`import easyocr

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext('3.jpg')
texts = [detection[1] for detection in result if detection[2] > 0.5]`
The output is
**['24,15']**

Comment: @BerlinBenilo thanks for suggestion, ill try it out and let you know. And no i dont have to stick with layoutparser. I tried multiple libraries and layoutparser had good results with other data, so i kept using it.

Comment: Good to hear. Let me know if you face issues.

Comment: Tried easyocr and it works great. I got 68% accuracy on non-preprocessed images and 79% on preprocessed images. I'll try to see if i can push it any higher with other preprocessing methods, but this is good enough as is.

Comment: Great!. For more accurate way of OCR, you can go with google vision but you have to subscribe for there api. Anyway happy to hear about your improved result. Happy coding :)